# Building a bootable USB stick - GRUB syntax

Tags: boot, grub2

So I have a usb stick that I've partitioned into 2 parts. The first part contains GRUB (Via grub-install) and some ISOs that I want to boot/install from.

Rather than start the Linux kernel on these ISOs immediately I want to start their own "Menu" that usually has useful options on it.

Is this menu actually inside Linux or is it external? (Logic says external since these menu items start Linux themselves)

So far I've guessed that this is a correct `grub.cfg`, but I'd like a more experienced eye to take a peek before I go booting from it.

```
# Config for GNU GRand Unified Bootloader (GRUB)
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg

# Timeout for menu
set timeout=-1

menuentry "Debian mini.iso x86_64" {
    loopback loop /boot/iso/debian-mini-x86_64-25.10.2013.iso
    rootnoverify (loop)
    chainloader +1
    boot
}
```

Will this bring up the same menu as if I just booted from a disc with this image burned on it?

Will this type of `menuentry` work for all images?

**Edit:** So it looks like you can't chainload loopback devices and I'll have to manually reconstruct all the boot entries from the isolinux settings files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't chainload loopbacks, but you can look at the iso's bootloader and copy/paste the boot options to grub. It's not pretty but it works.